# Original motivation for pairing definitions

Tags: elliptic-curves

Today the Weil and Tate pairings are used a lot in cryptography.
I'm curious, what was the original motivation of Weil and Tate for defining them? (Especially curious about Weil.)

Comment: [Closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/797892/11619).

Comment: I saw that, not sure that closely.

Comment: Upon rereading the discussion there I tend to agree. The title looked more promising :-(